# Generics declaration in Java

Tags: java, generics

```
// main
String[] data = {"a", "b", "c"};
Foo<?, ?> gen = proc(data);
// end main

...

public <T> Foo<T, Integer> proc(T[] a) {
    Foo<T, Integer> retval;

    // some procedure
    retval = new Foo<T, Integer>(result_from_procedure, 1);

    return retval;
}
```

Is it ok to declare an object as `Foo<?, ?> or Foo<?, Integer>` to make it more general so that it can save an object from `proc(T[] a)` with `T` different types?

Comment: Well, does it compile? Or are you asking whether it's a good idea?

Comment: I'm just asking if it's a good idea and if it's acceptable to use '?'.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. If you want to pass any type, you should declare `Foo<?, ?>`  
If you only want to allow Integers, use `Foo<?; Integer>`

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards (*) should be used in conjugation of extends or super bounds. For all other cases exact type argument should be used